# How to deploy Azure resources using GitLab Pipelines?

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy Azure Resources using GitLab pipelines. resources e.g. Resource Group, storage account, etc. using ARM/Powershell stored in GitLab CI and using GitLab pipelines how can I deploy any Azure resources?

Comment: Have you tried reading the given link: https://dev.to/raisingcode/using-github-actions-to-deploy-arm-templates-544m ? It does the same using Github Actions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you run into errors? Do you have a pipeline definition (`.gitlab-ci.yml` file) started that you need help with and can share? We'll need more information to help answer your question.

Comment: Hi Adam - I'm new to the GitLab. I'm using ADO for alll deployments and I'm good in ADO. And trying to replicate same in GitLab to see how I can do Azure Resource deployments using GitLab. I did lot of search but didn't find any straightforward way and videos or documentations around it and hence I raised this question here.

Answer (score 1):

You've to setup gitlab-ci.yml and use it in CI / CD on GitLab.

Please follow this [video tutorial from Azure DevOps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uewVGzNs2QU) explaining the process.
This tutorial covers all the steps you mentioned from 1-5.

Comment: I have already seen this video but it does not display the implementation steps, it just shows the web app deployment. Im looking how to create the service connection form GitLab to Azure subscription and do resource deployments.